# Angular Directive - Replace tags while embedding the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I am writing a directive which take templates according to the attribute provided.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Emu0eYVqtqH6MK9Eh2zR?p=preview)

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('sample', function($compile){
  var a = '<div>template 1</div>';
  var b = '<div>template 2</div>';

  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      type: '@'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element){
      var get_template = function(){
          if($scope.type == 'others'){
              return b;
          } else {
              return a;
          }
      };

      $($element).html(get_template()).show();
      $compile($($element).contents())($scope);
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<sample></sample>
<sample type="others"></sample>
```

Here `replace: true` works when we provide the template property inside the directive. Is there any way to get rid of the `<sample />` tag and just have the `<div />`.

There is also another approach,

```
app.directive('sample', function($compile, $templateCache){
  var a = '<div>template 1</div>';
  var b = '<div>template 2</div>';

  $templateCache.put('template1.html', a);
  $templateCache.put('template2.html', b);

  return {
    template: '<div ng-include="get_template()" />',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      type: '@'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element){
      var get_template = function(){
          if($scope.type == 'others'){
              return 'template2.html';
          } else {
              return 'template1.html';
          }
      };
    }
  }
});
```

But the above approach still has `<div ng-include />` as the parent for `<div>template1</div>` whereas I just need `<div>template`.

Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of restrict in the Angular make restrict to 'A' and add 'sample' as attribute.

Read more about restrict in directive : [AngularJS Directive Restrict A vs E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220976/angularjs-directive-restrict-a-vs-e)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `<ng-transclude>` instead and append the template to your element. That might hep. Something like below :

```
app.directive('sample', function($compile, $templateCache){
  var a = '<div>template 1</div>';
  var b = '<div>template 2</div>';

  $templateCache.put('template1.html', a);
  $templateCache.put('template2.html', b);

  return {
    template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div>',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      type: '@'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element){
          var elem_0 = angular.element($element.children()[0]);
          var templateToAppend = angular.element($compile( get_template() ));
          elem_0.append(templateToAppend);

      var get_template = function(){
          if($scope.type == 'others'){
              return 'template2.html';
          } else {
              return 'template1.html';
          }
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Let me know if you face any problems