# AngularJS use component as Input tag placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I have a localization component that looks like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.core')
    .component('i18n', {
      templateUrl: './i18n.html',
      bindings: {
        code: '@'
      },
      controller: i18n,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });


  i18n.$inject = ['langStrings'];

  function i18n(langStrings) {
    const vm = this;
    this.$onInit = () => {
      vm.text = langStrings.get(vm.code);
    };
  }
})();
```

The i18n template consists of a single line:

```
{{vm.text}}
```

This works great for displaying strings, but when I want to use the string in another component or in template as a placeholder for input tag, I don't know how to apply it. So for example how would I apply the components end result for inputs placeholder in another context?

Input in some other component or template.

```
<input 
    placeholder="<i18n code='searchPlaceholder'/>"
>
```

I am using angularJs 1.7.2

Comment: Doesn't this helps? `placeholder="{{vm.text}}"`

Comment: Sorry, I gave unclear instructions. Clarified the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input placeholder attribute is waiting for a string. `<i18n>` is a component rendering an HTML element like its name (restriction in directives as [Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220976/angularjs-directive-restrict-a-vs-e) witch component actually acts).

Angular can support [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) on an attribute. so basically, you need to create something like `placeholder="{{exp}}"` witch the exp evaluation will have to return a string.

1. Either you create a component rendering an input as an HTML
2. Use the method `{{langStrings.get(v)}}` and cast it to a var so use `placeholder="{{vm.text}}"` or `ng-init="z= lngs('asdf');" placeholder="{{z}}"`
3. Access element and change its attribute which can be done on [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#attributes) function or template function of the component.
4. Or basically, you create something that it casts a string and not render its HTML. A Custom Service 4 example using i18n.

try an easier way to change elements attribute on a directive using the link function

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function i18n(langStrings) {
    return {
      restrict: 'CA',
      scope: {
        code: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        //attrs.$set('placeholder', langStrings.get(scope.code));
        // observe changes to interpolated attribute
        attrs.$observe('code', function(value) {
          let text = langStrings.get(value);
          elem.attr('placeholder', text);
        });
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/angularjs-difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods
        //scope.$watch('code', function(newval) {
        //let text = langStrings.get(newval);
        //elem.attr('placeholder', text);
        //});
      },
    }
  }

  function testCtrl($scope, langStrings) {
    $scope.lngs = function(v) {
      return langStrings.get(v);
    };
    return this;
  }

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .component('i18c', {
      bindings: {
        code: '@'
      },
      template: function($element, $attrs, langStrings) {
        let c = langStrings.get($attrs.code);
        return `<input placeholder="` + c + `">`;
      }
    })
    .directive('i18nCustom', i18n)
    .controller('testCtrl', testCtrl)
    //i18n.$inject = ['langStrings'];
    .factory('langStrings', function() {
      this.get = (v) => {
        return v + '-transformed';
      };
      return this;
    })


})();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <input class="i18n-custom" code='test-class'>
  <input i18n-custom code='test-attr'>
  <input ng-init="z = lngs('test ctrl fun');" placeholder="{{z}}">
  <i18c code="Test Comp"></i18c>
</body>
```